# SPARQL combine Optional and Filter

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

SPARQL beginner here - running queries on WikiData: https://query.wikidata.org

I am using the following query to return all people with occupation of politician and country of citizenship is USA, and their date of birth.  As not all records contain a Date of Birth, I have made this `OPTIONAL`.

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?dobLabel
WHERE
{
?person wdt:P106 wd:Q82955 .
?person wdt:P27 wd:Q30 .
OPTIONAL {?person wdt:P569 ?dob}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```

I now need to add a `FILTER` that only returns entries with a date of birth greater than January 1, 1960, however I still want the records that have no Date of Birth value returned.  How do I combine `OPTIONAL` and `FILTER`?

Comment: put the filter after the OPTIONAL: `FILTER(!bound(?dob) || ?dob > "1980-08-20T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)`

Comment: by the way, you should use the correct variable names. Obviously `?person` is not bound if you use `?item` in the query pattern

Comment: Thanks that looks like it works.  I've updated my post to correct the variable names.